# Elixir IEX stalls before showing prompt, and doesn't accept input

Tags: erlang, elixir, elixir-iex, beam

I recently tried to start iex. I typed `iex` in the shell (I tried several shells, just in case) and iex doesn't provide any prompt or the like. It just sits there, and if I type special keys like arrows they are escaped and output. If i type `control-c` it shows me the standard beam interrupt. I checked that `iex` was pointing to the right place and not oddly aliased, and it seems to be correct. How do I go about troubleshooting this?

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing elixir (but not erlang yet), but that didn't fix it. Are there any cached files I can check or delete?

Comment: Don’t you have some configuration [`.iex.exs`](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html#module-the-iex-exs-file) files that mess up the startup process? Is erlang shell start normally with `erl`?

Comment: Good idea with `erl`. it fails the same way. So I uninstalled and reinstalled erlang (is 1.3 gb for installed erlang files normal?). No dice, sadly. same issue. But now i know it's erlang and not elixir.

Comment: Please share details about your OS. Also please confirm you have no `~/.iex.exs` file. On my machine: `du --max-depth=0 /usr/lib/erlang` results in 124M.

Comment: No `.iex.exs` file.

Comment: OS is mac OS 10.13.2. Erlang and elixir are the newest versions installed with homebrew.

Comment: Since this seems to be down to an error on your machine, I vote to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so turned out to be an erlang issue. After scouring my drive for erlang related files, I was able to get it to work after a re-install. Files I deleted before re-install:

- `~/.erlang.cookie` (the most likely candidate. contained a string similar to this: "AMVBSKDKEI", sadly, I don't have the exact string anymore)
- the cached home-brew bottles (unlikely, but deleted them just to be sure)
- rabbit mq (maybe not the issue, but it was an erlang dependent package I had left installed previously)

`/usr/share/file/magic/erlang` looks to be part of `file(1)` and not erlang directly. Left that alone and got it to work.

Comment: Thanks to the other posters for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html).  I'm specifically thinking of this part of the page:

> The .erlang startup file
>
> When Erlang/OTP is started, the system searches for a file named .erlang in the directory where Erlang/OTP is started. If not found,
>   the user's home directory is searched for an .erlang file.
>
> If an .erlang file is found, it is assumed to contain valid Erlang expressions. These expressions are evaluated as if they were input to
>   the shell.

You'll want to see if there's an .erlang file anywhere; this would alter the startup of the Erl shell. That page also contains a bit of detail about environment variables that may affect the behavior of `erl` as well.

Comment: There are no `.erlang` files in directories I have access to (everything except special system dirs).

I have no environment variables set that contain `erl` or `elixir` or `iex`

Comment: I know you already tried it but I would seriously try to remove all traces of Erlang from the machine.  Something's broken but it's hard to say what.  See if you may have an older version of Erlang on the machine too--that may cause you a problem.

Comment: There is a `/usr/share/file/magic/erlang` file remaining after I uninstall erlang. Any idea what that is?